# What is the preliminary scale in M-estimates for regression

Tags: regression, robust, estimators

I'm trying to get aquainted with robust regression methods and there's something about M-estimators that I don't understand.

In "Robust statistics" (Maronna, Martin, Yohai) it is said that if both our x's and y's are random, the M-estimator of regression is given as a solution to

$$
\sum \rho (\frac{r_i (\hat{\beta})}{\hat{\sigma}}) = min
$$

where $\rho$ is a bounded $\rho$ function and $\hat{\sigma}$ is a "high breakdown preliminary scale". What is that "preliminary scale" supposed to be? How do I understand preliminary in that context?

Comment: can you also give the page number?

Comment: They refer to an initial estimate of $\sigma$ (some measure of scale) that is itself 'high breakdown' (that is, doesn't 'break down' at small levels of arbitrary contamination). Such high breakdown estimators for scale will have been discussed - check the book.

Comment: Glen_b, can you elaborate? For what initial values this high BP measure of scale (like MAD, I take it?) is estimated for? In the section for fixed X matrix it is stated that they use the L1 estimator, then count the MAD of L1 residuals, and this value is inserted into the equation. Is that correct?

Comment: The preliminary scale is the described in the section 2.7.2 of the book. Weighted with the bisquare $\rho$-function. The book is a bit confusing